# How to populate div element on change with angular 2 select?

Tags: angular

This is my html template

```
<form #animalForm="ngForm">
<div class="animal-profile-search">
    <input type="text" class="animal-profile-search-bar" placeholder="Enter Animal Name">
    <select [(ngModel)]="animal" class="animal-profile-select" (ngModelChange)="onSelect($event)" ngControl="animal">
        <option *ngFor="#animal of animals" [ngValue]="animal">{{animal.common}}</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="animal-profile-body">
    <div class="animal-profile-name">
        <div class="animal-profile-label">Common Name:</div>
        <div class="animal-profile-value">{{animal.common}}</div>
        <div class="animal-profile-label">Scientific Name:</div>
        <div class="animal-profile-value">Value</div>
    </div>
    <div class="animal-profile-image"></div>
    <div class="animal-profile-natural-history">
        {{animal | json}}
    </div>
</div>
```

and the component

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AnimalService } from '../services/animal.service';
import { Animal } from '../DTOModels/animal';
import { Http, HTTP_PROVIDERS } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Component({
    selector: 'data-result',
    templateUrl : './app/components/animal-profile.component.html', 
    providers: [HTTP_PROVIDERS,AnimalService],
    inputs: ['animals', 'animal']
})

export class AnimalProfile{
    animals: Array<any>;
    animal: Animal;
    constructor(http: Http){
        http.get("/animals")
            .map(res => res.json())
            .subscribe(animals => this.animals = animals,
                       error => console.log("Error:" +error),
                       ()=>this.animal = this.animals[0]);


    }

    onSelect(inAnimal: Animal){
        this.animal = inAnimal;
        var common = document.getElementById('common');

        console.log(this.animal.latin);
    }
}
```

The above displays the json for the correct chosen model, but it wont let me show the correct value for the common name which is a parameter of the animal model. I have tried many different things, such has placing ngModel with in the div, nothing up to this point has worked. I would appreciate any insight anyone might have in relation to this problem. I am still learning the new syntax with Angular 2 and am about to just use JQuery to populate the elements. I would really just like to stick with the Angular 2 way of doing things. The idea would for a user to select an animal in the list and then the values below would be populated.

Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting your data using an asynchronous HTTP call, so when the template is first rendered, the `animals` and `animal` properties are not defined.  You can use the [safe navigation operator](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#safe-navigation-operator) to guard against undefined and null values:

```
{{animal?.common}}
```

Note that `{{animal | json}}` works because the [JsonPipe](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/JsonPipe-class.html) guards against undefined and null values.

Comment: Thanks for your response ill try it